# How to update multiple values in different nodes simultaneously in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

[Screenshot of my Database in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVOTw.png)

Here I have a node called products. In that, I have many child nodes. All those nodes have a common value called product stock. I need to update the product stock value of all the nodes inside the product. How can I do that in android studio (Java) because I'm developing a shopping application? Need help.

```
private void updateStock(String quantity, String availablestock) {

        int qty = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
        int stk_avl = Integer.parseInt(availablestock);

        int stk = stk_avl - qty;

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        hashMap.put("ProductStock", ""+stk);


        //update to database
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.child(shopUid).child("Products").child(productId)
                .updateChildren(hashMap)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        //update success
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        
                        Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Updated...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
```

The flow is:
The user adds the products to the cart. In the cart, I have ordernow button. So when the user clicks order now, the products' quantity in his cart should be subtracted from the product stock value which is in the products node. But when this code runs, for example, assume I have 5 products in the cart, this code is updating product stock for only 1 product (last added product in the cart).
How can I make it update all the products?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to update multiple children that exist under a particular node, you have to create a query and use `updateChildren` method as seen below:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = dbFirebaseDatabase.child("Users");
DatabaseReference productsRef = usersRef.child(shopUid).child("Products");
DatabaseReference additionalUserInfoRef = rootRef.child("AdditionalUserInfo");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("ProductStock", newValueOfTypeInt);
            ds.getRef().updateChildren(map);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
productsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

If you want, you can also attach a listener to the `.updateChildren(map)` to see if something goes wrong.

Comment: I tried the above method. But it still has some issues. It is updating all the child values that's fine. But it is updating all the child values with single value (i had 2 products in cart. this code updated the latest added product's stock value to all the products in db). How to alter it to update only the products currently in cart with it's respective values??

Comment: Yes, it's updating all the child values. Isn't this what you want? Your question is, *How to update multiple values in different nodes*. Which is what the solution does. If you however want to add different values for each node, then you should iterate the desired node to get those values, and then use the solution above to change each one of them with the corresponding value. Don't forget to have a relationship between them.

Comment: I'm not getting this. Can u pls modify the code above. It would be helpful for me to implement. I'm not that much familiar with this yet.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question so I can get the stocks from the cart and (decrement) modify the stock in the products node. Besides that, Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. However, we are willing to assist with your existing code. You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer (provided code) and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: Yes I'm getting. But I'm in learning stage. So I'm not aware much about these code. For iterating the node, how can I use a for loop inside it. below is my structure of my db or u can refer the attached image along with question in the beginning.
users:
UID:
Products:(under products I have a list of products. Each product is a node. The node name is timestamp which i used as product id) 
12334566: (this  is a product) 
--
--
- (product stock)
Like wise in the above structure I have some products. 
In what basis i can iterate to get my correct result....

Comment: If you are in the learning stage, then you should try that yourself. So give it a try and ask another question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if something else comes up.

Comment: yeah done!! Thanks